# Made use of undefined node - WinBUGS beginner

Tags: r, winbugs, r2winbugs

I'm attempting to run a model using a large data set (5.9million rows). I get the error `made use of undefined node ...`

I've tried lots of sample data (from my larger data set) which go through the model fine, until the sample data set size reaches ~8900 rows at which point the error occurs.

I can try to produce some sample data to demonstrate the model if necessary, however didn't know whether it was just related to the amount of data I'm using? I'm slightly confused by the error message as the variable (node) in question is defined elsewhere and works fine with sample data.

The model is fairly lengthy so I have been expecting memory issues etc. already.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet managed to run the full model due to other errors, however I believe I solved this one.

3 of my variables contained `NA` values which supposedly WinBUGS doesn't like. After removing the `NA` values the model ran smoothly with all of my samples.